# Winforms ActiveX control hangs TSTCON32.EXE on exit

Tags: c#, winforms, activex, winforms-interop

I have a simple Windows Forms UserControl with a COM-callable ActiveX wrapper. When I run the control in TSTCON32 (the ActiveX Control Test Container), the TSTCON32.EXE process hangs on exit and must be ended with the likes of Task Manager. (Dispose() has been called on the control.) There have been several postings regarding this issue over the years, but no one seems to have resolved it satisfactorily.

Does anyone know of a definitive fix for this issue?